# How to check whether my proxy server allows ssh connection or not in Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, ssh, proxy

My college uses a proxy server with firewall for providing internet. I am unable to make a ssh connection to my AWS instance through my college internet, though I can do so through my data modem. I want to check if my proxy server firewall allows port 22/ssh connection or not?

Answer (score 1):

You can use netcat to test this:

```
if nc -z remote.host.example.com 22; then
    echo "Connection to TCP/22 succeeded"
else
    echo "Connection to TCP/22 failed"
fi
```

Comment: I don't know about netcat, will you please tell me how can I use netcat?

Comment: It's a handy tool for testing (and using) network connections.  You can install it with `sudo apt install netcat`, and read all about it with `man nc`.